# Regular Expressions - Regex for specific characters!

Tags: apex, validation, regular-expressions

Which is the Regex for these symbols?

`-`, `–`, `%`, `/`, `.`, `""`, `«»`, `''`, `'`, `<`, `>`, `&`, `:`, `(`, `)`, `!`, `^`, `*`

Ι need to Replace them all with Space.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try

```
String r = t.replaceAll('[-%/.<>&:]',' ');
```

// Put all your symbols here.

Example:

```
String t = 'I-am%Noor/who/are:you<I>am';
String r = t.replaceAll('[-_%/."<>&:()!/*/^]',' ');
System.Debug(r);
```

Output:

```
I am Noor who are you I am
```

Comment: Thank you so much!!

Answer (score 1):

Just adding another option here: you can utilize some great playground tools to figure it our or test out your regex before putting it into your code.

https://regexr.com/

and then a great resource for learning regex as well

https://regexone.com/

Comment: Awesome! Thanks Kris:)